# In the conjugate gradient method, prove that if $v^{(k)} = 0$, then $Ax^{(k)} = b$

Tags: numerical-methods, gradient-descent

In the conjugate gradient method, prove that if $v^{(k)} = 0$, then $Ax^{(k)} = b$. I'm working on this numerical analysis problem and was wondering if anyone could help me out. Im not quite sure where to even begin.

Comment: what is $v^{(k)}$? The wikipedia article uses $r_k$ and $p_k$. (The statement is true for both)

Comment: also, lazy answer: If you already know that CG always converges exactly (after at most $n$ steps, if there are no rounding errors), it is easy: If $v_k=0$, then the $x$ does not change anymore, so convergence must be reached already.